# GPU Chipset Detection

Tags: objective-c, graphics, hardware, system, gpu

Seeking most efficient method for retrieving the GPU model in Objective-C or Carbon. I want to avoid using system_profiler because it is slow, but if it comes down to that I am willing to use it, but I wanna exhaust other options first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try glGetString(GL_RENDERER) from the OpenGL library.